# Как узнать на какое изображение навели камеру Unity&Vuforia

Tags: android, unity3d, vuforia

мне нужно  узнать на какое изображение навели камеру. Приложение под андроид сделано при помощи Unity&Vuforia. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Информации в вопросе не много, но предполагаю, что Вы используете Vuforia Cloud Recognition (как вариант).
Если да, то последовательность действий там такая: в проекте Unity Вы добавили Vuforia Engine AR (стабильная версия на январь 2021 - 8.1.12) через Package Manager, создали лицензионный ключ для своего проекта ([на официальном сайте](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Vuforia-License-Manager.html)). Затем добавили АR Camera, в Vuforia Configuration ввели созданный лицензионный ключ, добавили Сloud Recognition и Image Target. Создали облачную базу данных Cloud Database [по инструкции](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-To-Work-with-Cloud-Databases.html) и в Cloud Recognition вставили ключи созданной базы данных.

В таком случае, чтобы узнать, что именно распознано, можно с помощью скрипта, который нужно прикрепить к объекту Cloud Recognition (скрипт SimpleCloudHandler):

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;
using System.Collections;

 public class SimpleCloudHandler : MonoBehaviour, IObjectRecoEventHandler
 {
     private CloudRecoBehaviour mCloudRecoBehaviour;

 void Start()
 {
     mCloudRecoBehaviour = GetComponent();

     if (mCloudRecoBehaviour)
     {
         mCloudRecoBehaviour.RegisterEventHandler(this);
     }
     mCloudRecoBehaviour.CloudRecoEnabled = true;

   }

 public void OnInitialized(TargetFinder targetFinder)
 {
     Debug.Log("Инициализировано Cloud Reco");
 }
 public void OnInitError(TargetFinder.InitState initError)
 {
     Debug.Log("Ошибка инициализации Cloud Reco " + initError.ToString());
 }
 public void OnUpdateError(TargetFinder.UpdateState updateError)
 {
     Debug.Log("Ошибка обновления Cloud Reco " + updateError.ToString());
 }

 public void OnStateChanged(bool scanning)
 {

     if (scanning)
     {
         ObjectTracker tracker = TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker();
         tracker.GetTargetFinder().ClearTrackables(false);
     }

 }

 public void OnNewSearchResult(TargetFinder.TargetSearchResult targetSearchResult)
 {
     TargetFinder.CloudRecoSearchResult cloudRecoSearchResult = (TargetFinder.CloudRecoSearchResult)targetSearchResult;

    string nameOfTarget = cloudRecoSearchResult.TargetName; //название объекта из Вашей базы
    string metadataOfTarget = cloudRecoSearchResult.MetaData; //данные из текстового файла, который Вы привязали к своему объекту в базе данных Cloud Database

     //Используйте эти данные, как вам нужно, например, создайте элемент UI Text и выведите на экран название распознанного объекта

 }
}
```